# How can I get the average of the top N rows of a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying

```
SELECT AVG(q."level")
FROM "Questions" q, "QuestionScores" qs
WHERE qs."QuestionId" = q."id"
AND qs."StudentId"=13
AND q."TopicId" = 45
AND qs."version" = 8
ORDER BY qs."score" DESC
LIMIT 3
```

But it says that I need to have `qs."score"` in a GROUP BY or be used in an aggregate function. All I want is to have the top 3 question levels (ranked by score) averaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the top n row *first* using a subquery, *then* get the average:

```
SELECT AVG(level) FROM (
    SELECT q.level
    FROM Questions q, QuestionScores qs
    WHERE qs.QuestionId = q.id
    AND qs.StudentId=13
    AND q.TopicId = 45
    AND qs.version = 8
    ORDER BY qs.score DESC
    LIMIT 3
) x
```

---

I recommend you use the modern (over 25 years old) `join` syntax:

```
   SELECT AVG(level) FROM (
    SELECT q.level
    FROM Questions q
    JOIN QuestionScores qs ON qs.QuestionId = q.id
    WHERE qs.StudentId=13
    AND q.TopicId = 45
    AND qs.version = 8
    ORDER BY qs.score DESC
    LIMIT 3
) x
```

Comment: Looks correct, but I wouldn't ever promote using commas in the `from` clause -- explicit `join` syntax is much better.

Comment: @sgeddes agreed - I posted the minimal change. But added in a joined version